# List Unique Strings in Source Code

Tags: string, windows

I am after a utility that will list unique strings in many source code files. Anything in [az,AZ,09,.] of length at least 1 character. Once I find them I will make a list of strings with old values and new values beside them.

I tried `findstr /R [a-z] *.*` but it just lists the lines. I want one string per line without any special characters (eg '"![]{}()*/+=- etc).

Many of the linux utilities have been ported to Windows and I'd be happy to use  them like [Grep equivalent for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/grep-equivalent-for-windows-7) or [Is there a better way to do this command to find strings in a file excluding special characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/581561/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-this-command-to-find-strings-in-a-file-excluding-spe)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously under windows 10, you'd install the windows 10 linux stuff... but on windows 7, you have the venerable cygwin.  https://www.cygwin.com/

After installing cygwin, you'll want to use something to chop up your input into "words."  Sed or awk are your friends here.  You might even fall back to something like python or perl (both can be installed in cygwin).

That said, python installs natively in windows just fine.

hrm... this should about do it.  run this once per file you want to analyze.

```
include sys,string

    for line in sys.stdin.readline():
      state=0
      for c in line:
        if c in letters+numbers:
          sys.stdout.write(c)
          state=1
        elif state == 1:
          sys.stdout.write('\n')
          state=0
      if state == 1:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Now... I post that... and it satisfies your constraint... but by strings you probably mean things in quotes ... or variables...?

Comment: I might have to give the pythin a miss. python codewords.py < Base64.CPP
  File "codewords.py", line 1
    include sys,string
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of typos in variables that I want to correct. I am really looking for the specifics of the command line. It seems to be easy for straight text but not within the context of special characters within C code. I have no intention of writing C just fixing the declarations.

Comment: You do not want to do this! ... Cygwin package ... will download and install tens of gigabytes to your computer.